# Prevent fullcalendar from accepting every "droppable" object

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using the jquery "dialog" feature to provide popup windows with fullcalendar.  I use the "modal: true" setting to disable the parent page.  However, fullcalendar tries to interact with the modal accepting it as a droppable object.  As a result when you drag the modal the calendar days underneath highlight.  When you let go the fullcalendar errors....

Answer (score 1):

Or set the option `droppable = false`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
drop-accept: 'div class of object'
```

under the calendar.